# Load ApplicationContext using spring in session in Swing Window Application

Tags: java, spring, swing, spring-mvc, session

I am developing Swing Window Application with Spring.
Now, question can i store ApplicationContext in some session variable on initiating first Swing Window and use it throughout window application until user close application.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:**/Bean*.xml");
                        LoginPage loginPage = (LoginPage) context.getBean("loginPage");
                        loginPage.frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:**/Bean*.xml");

LoginPage loginPage = (LoginPage) context.getBean("loginPage");
```

As shown above to get loginPage bean from spring i need to get it from ApplicationContext.
As shown above Can i store `"context"` variable in some session variable so that I can use that `context` variable any time in application until user close application.

The reason for this issue, i always need to create `context` variable and then i will get desired bean from it. But all the time creating context variable is not the proper why I think it may create problems for memory.

Comment: why do you whant to "save" the context into a session ? You don't need the context in a spring application. Use dependency injection.

Comment: Can you provide a way for dependancy injection ?

Comment: May Base Class is `MainClass` , 
from `MainClass` business logic is called which is in `MainRulesClass` and from `MainRulesClass` Database objects is called which are in `MainDAOClass` .
`MainClass -> MainRulesClass -> MainDAOClass`

To access business rules in MainClass in need to create object of MainRulesClass and to access DAO methods i need to create object of `MainDAOClass` in `MainRulesClass`

i have put bean entry in Bean.xml so every time to access other i need to get context and then create object of that class from bean.

Comment: Did you ever use spring ? You can use dependency injection in xml configuration, java class Configuration or using annotation such as Autowired or Ressource take a look at the spring documentation